# Select data from database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have some data in a mysql database.The database every time consists of a different number of rows.

An example of my table would be :

```
id  team1  team2  home  away  tip
----------------------------------
12   xxx    yyy   zzz   kkk
43   xxx    yyy   zzz   kkk
.     .      .     .     .
.     .      .     .     .
```

So what i need to do is loop through every row of the table and be able to get the data from that row so i can create the tip.

I am a bit confused on how i could do that with pdo.

What i ve tried so far is try to get a column of data like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tablename");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->fetchColumn();
    echo $result[0];
```

But even that , that i would expect to give me back the first id , which is 12 in this case, just returns me 1. Any ideas here?

Comment: `echo $result[0];` returns the first character of the scalar `$result`, as you are using `->fetchColumn` to only fetch 1 column, not the whole row. So, either `echo $result`, or use `$result=$stmt->fetch();`. Currently, what's happening can be compared to this: `$result="12"; echo $result[0];` (which, as you can test, echoes `'1'` indeed.

Comment: `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if($result){echo $result['id'];}` should work. `$result` is going to either be boolean FALSE or an array so a simple check will avoid undesireable errors

Comment: @wrikken, when i use $result=$stmt->fetch(); does indeed work. but when i try to echo $result[1] gives me an error. How can i get all the column in an array so i can loop through the results?

Comment: If you `SELECT id FROM tablename`, you only _have_ one column, so, `$result[1]` will not be set indeed. Alter your query to return the other columns, and they'll appear in `$result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tablename");
try{
    $stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $err){
    //some logging function
}
//loop through each row
while($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //select column by key and use
    echo $result['id'];
}
```

alternatively you could use fetchAll to select whole dataset into a variable. Then you wouldn't need to loop

Heres a useful resource for PDO:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: This is relevant to me

Answer (score 0):

```
$getUsers = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC");
$getUsers->execute();
$users = $getUsers->fetchAll();
```

May be helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the result without index

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fetch (with FETCH_NUM) instead of fetchColumn

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tablename");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop throught you can use the while loop 
and below is the example

```
<?php 

$stmt =("SELECT id FROM tablename");
$result=$db->prepare($stmt );
$result->execute();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$id = $row['id'];
 echo $id;
}
?>
```